# Shell script: Parse URL for iFrame and get iFrame URL

Tags: bash, shell, sed, wget, parse-url

I want to parse my website, search for the `<iframe>`-Tag and get the URL (attr `src=""`).

I tried it like this:

```
url=`wget -O - http://my-url.com/site 2>&1 | grep iframe`
echo $url
```

With this, i get the whole HTML line:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/AAAAAAAA?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="480" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>     </div>
```

Well, how can i parse now the URL?
I tried it with a few `sed`-syntaxes, but didn't make it :( Here's what I tried:

```
wget -O - http://myurl.com/ 2>&1 | grep iframe | sed "s/<iframe src/\\n<iframe src/g"
```

Kind regards,
Matt ;)

Comment: Please show what you tried, so we can help you understand how you went wrong. You don't learn anything by just copying an answer.

Comment: Well I tried it with this: `wget -O - http://myurl.com/ 2>&1 | grep iframe` and then tried to cut the html out except for the url: `sed "s/<iframe src/\\n<iframe src/g"`
I'm new into regex, so don't blame me :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/<iframe/s/^.*<iframe src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

You don't need `grep`, `sed` pattern matching can do that. Then you use a capture group with `\(...\)` to pick out the URL inside the quotes in the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sed, cut is sufficient:

```
~$ url='<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/AAAAAAAA?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="480" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>     </div>'
~$ echo $url|cut -d'"' -f 2
//player.vimeo.com/video/AAAAAAAA?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0
```

Comment: It's working but it also cuts my url: `http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=201656958&id=164774203&has....h=72fdb2f61426b6c5&hd=1`. It just shortens the string, haha :D

Comment: @Matt I don't see that url in your example.